# как запретить латиницу при оформлении заказа в woocommerce?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

В форме оформления заказа надо запретить пользователям писать имя и фамилию на английском языке.

Использовал данный код, чтобы это реализовать, но он работает некоректно - возникает ошибка:

- Artem NO LATIN = ALLOW ONLY CYRILLIC LETTERS and hyphen
  add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'Speedplus_com_ua_latin_checkout_fields');
  function Speedplus_com_ua_latin_checkout_fields() {
  $billing_first_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'billing_first_name');

  $billing_last_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'billing_last_name');
  if (strlen(trim(preg_replace('/^[А-Яа-яЁё-]+$/', '', $billing_first_name))) > 0) {
  wc_add_notice(__('Будь ласка, напишіть **ВАШІ ІНІЦІАЛИ** українською, або російською'), 'error');
  }

if (strlen(trim(preg_replace('/^[А-Яа-яЁё-]+$/', '', $billing_last_name))) > 0) {
wc_add_notice(__('Будь ласка, напишіть **ВАШІ ІНІЦІАЛИ** українською, або російською'), 'error');
}
}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как запретить оформление заказа на английском языке, woocommerce?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1370560/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b5-woocommerce)

Comment: Код надо оформить в вопросе как код, а не текстом. Используйте три символа обратной кавычки ` на пустой строке в начале и конце куска кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'Speedplus_com_ua_latin_checkout_fields');
function Speedplus_com_ua_latin_checkout_fields() {
    $billing_first_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'billing_first_name');
    
    $billing_last_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'billing_last_name');
 if (strlen(trim(preg_replace('/^[АаБбВвГгДдЕеЁёЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯяІіЄєЇїҐґ.\s\'\-]+$/', '', $billing_first_name))) > 0) {
        wc_add_notice(__('Будь ласка, напишіть ваші ІНІЦІАЛИ українською або російською.'), 'error');
    }
 
 if (strlen(trim(preg_replace('/^[АаБбВвГгДдЕеЁёЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯяІіЄєЇїҐґ.\s\'\-]+$/', '', $billing_last_name))) > 0) {
        wc_add_notice(__('Будь ласка, напишіть ваше ПРІЗВИЩЕ українською або російською.'), 'error');
    } 
}
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Можно методом перебора проверить, есть ли в строке латинские символы, лучше конечно же через регулярки, но если текст небольшой то этот вариант подойдет.

```
function is_latin($str) {
    
    foreach (str_split(strtolower($str))as $char) {
        $ord = ord($char);
        if($char >= 97 && $char <= 122) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}

if(is_latin($billing_last_name)) {
    wc_add_notice(__('Будь ласка, напишіть ВАШІ ІНІЦІАЛИ українською, або російською'), 'error');
}
```

Но этот код запретит именно латинницу, т.е какой нибудь китаец сможет оформить заказ на свое имя без проблем.